# Figure/Pictures Turns When Downloaded (Solved)

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, includegraphics

quite new here, but I have a small problem and I hope some of you guys can help me a little.
I've made a template for my LaTeX use regarding my university assignments, but I've run into a 'little' problem. When I use pictures taken from my DSLR (Camera), the picture looks fine in Overleaf, but when downlaoded the picture turns.
I've tried to delete all the picture meta data, but this didn't work.
If I download a picture from the internet, it works.
I've tried changing the extention from .jpg to .pgn, but this didn't help ether.
I don't really know whats happening and I hope some of you can help :)
I've included the code and pictures of the problem.
The problem is with picture: _MG_0003.JPG

Thanks for reading :)

```
\newcommand{\thesisAuthor}{First-Name Last-Name}
\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{Tile}
\newcommand{\thesisDegree}{course or degree}
\newcommand{\university}{Aarhus University}
\newcommand{\institut}{Dept. of Electrical \& Computer Engineering}
\newcommand{\ProjectDuration}{Month, Year - Month, Year}

\newcommand{\coverbaggrundimage}{settings/cover3/Billeder/_MG_0003.JPG}
\newcommand{\universityLogoCover}{settings/cover3/ausegl_blaa.png}
\newcommand{\universityLogoTitle}{settings/cover3/sender_logo(3).jpg}

\newcommand*\makecover{
    % Clearing the page and removing page number
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    %\backgroundsetup{contents = {}}

    %% Use the Tikz library positioning
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    % Defining where everything needs to go
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

    \node[above=0,inner sep=0] at (current page.south) {\includegraphics[height=1\paperheight, width=1\paperwidth]{\coverbaggrundimage}};

    %\node[rotate=90,below right=5cm and .3cm] at (current page.west) {\color{White} \university};
    
    \node[above=0.5,inner sep=0] at (current page.south) {\fontsize{1}{1}\color{CoverTittleTextsColor} LaTeX template made by: First-Name Last-Name};

    \node[above right=0.2cm and 0.2cm] at (current page.south west) {%
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{\universityLogoCover}};

    \node[below=2cm,fill=Black, minimum width={\paperwidth},inner ysep=25pt,opacity=0.6,text opacity=1] at (current page.north) {%
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\paperwidth}
            \fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont\color{CoverTittleTextsColor}{\thesisTitle} \\[1.5ex]
            \fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont\color{CoverSubtitleTextsColor}{\thesisDegree} \\[0.75ex]
            \fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont\color{CoverArthorTextsColor}{\thesisAuthor}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
}

\makecover
```

[image: Cover Inside Overleaf, Before Downloaded]

[image: Cover When Downloaded]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am pretty sure that you did not delete the Exif meta data that contains information about the rotation of the picture. Try opening the file with Gimp (or Photoshop) and check.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Holy Banana! It worked! But quite a hasse to delete it :(